# Asp.net EF populate panel from database only x elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have this method:

```
List<JobDescriptions> jobs = (from x in db.JobDescriptions select x)
     .OrderByDescending(y => y.DataAdaugarii)
     .ToList();
```

And I populate a panel like this:

```
JobReqModel jobReq = new JobReqModel();
List<JobDescriptions> jobs = jobReq.GetAllJobsOrderedByDate();

if (jobs != null)
{
    foreach (JobDescriptions job in jobs)
    {
    Panel jobPanel = new Panel();
    .
    .
```

I want to populate my panel only with X elements not all entries from database. I watched on panel properties I found nothing and I have only methods like First() Last() and rest of them I have no idea how to use them, I am thinking about Count() right now but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I print out some queries from database with a Panel and I want to print out a specified number, not all entries, for example now I try method "Take()", I want just 4 so Take(4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take (let's say) 10 elements from database do this

```
List<JobDescriptions> jobs = (from x in db.JobDescriptions select x)
     .OrderByDescending(y => y.DataAdaugarii)
     .Take(10) // this limits the result set
     .ToList();
```

Comment: I will mark this answers when this 6 minutes runs out. I was close, but I had ToList() before Take on my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function Take() to return a specified number of entries. In conjunction with Skip() you could implement a paging functionality.

```
List<JobDescriptions> jobs = db.JobDescriptions
    .OrderByDescending(y => y.DataAdaugarii)
    .Skip(10) // Will ignore 10 entries
    .Take(10) // Will only return up to 10 entries
    .ToList();
```